# Symptoms and its disease database design

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, database

Im working with android health application which will display human body parts such as head, chest etc.. For now I have three tables such as symptoms, diseases and symptom_disease table which will link those two table. If user select symptom such as dizziness, syncope, asthenia and others, then it will display hypertensive disease. But it will have problem when user select only one symptoms let say dizziness, it will also display the same disease. How do i differentiate this things? and how to implement it.

**This is my symptom table**

```
s_id    | s_name    | s_part
1       |dizziness  | Head
2       |syncope    | Head
3       |asthenia   | Head
```

**Disease table**

```
d_id    | d_name             | d_desc
1       |hypertensive disease| ....
```

**Symptom_disease table**

```
s_id | d_id
1    | 1
2    | 1
3    | 1
```

I use this query to get the disease

```
SELECT d.d_name, d.d_desc, s.symp_name 
FROM symtoms s 
    LEFT JOIN symptom_disease sd ON sd.sid = s.sid 
    LEFT JOIN diseases d ON d.did = sd.did 
WHERE s.sid IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY d.d_name
```

The problem here is when user select only one disease, I dont want it show the disease because one symptoms does not show that the user is ill. So, I need a suggestion on how to implement this. I have see a solution which require me to add rank/weight inside symptom_disease table. But I dont know how to implement this method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a desired output for your question?

Comment: Perhaps add a column to the disease table to indicate the minimum number of symptoms required before SELECTing that disease.

Comment: Or perhaps add a column to the symptom_disease table to assign the probability that symptom is related to that disease.  And add a column to the disease table to indicate a minimum probability before SELECTing that disease.

Comment: "The problem here is when user select only one disease, I dont want it show the disease because one symptoms does not show that the user is ill. 
"??

Comment: @e4c5 My point is let say user select only one symptoms, then the system will output the disease which is probably wrong because one symptom like dizziness does not meant that the user having hypertensive disease.

Comment: @LONG if you mean by what is the output, then the output should be the name of the disease. correct me if I wrong

Comment: @AndrewS thanks. I got your point on adding the new column. However can you show me on how to implement it in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic approach to use something like a probability column to determine the likelihood of a particular disease.

For diseases table:

```
1 Flu
2 Lyme
```

For symptoms table:

```
1 Muscle Aches
2 Headache
3 Fatigue
4 Fever
5 Vomiting
6 Tick Bite
```

For disease_symptom table:

```
s_id  d_id  probability
1     1     0.2
2     1     0.2
3     1     0.2
4     1     0.2
5     1     0.2
1     2     0.1
2     2     0.1
3     2     0.1
4     2     0.1
6     2     0.6
```

So if a patient says that have symptoms 2, 4, and 5, then

```
select d_name, sum(probability)
from disease, disease_symptom
where disease.d_id = disease_symptom.d_id
and s_id in (2, 4, 5)
group by d_name
order by sum(probability) desc
```

is

```
Flu   0.6
Lyme  0.2
```

so Flu is the most likely.

But if the patient has symptoms 2, 4, and 6, then

```
select d_name, sum(probability)
from disease, disease_symptom
where disease.d_id = disease_symptom.d_id
and s_id in (2, 4, 6)
group by d_name
order by sum(probability) desc
```

is

```
Lyme   0.8
Flue   0.4
```

so Lyme disease is mostly likely.

Comment: hey. thanks for your long explanation. will try this now

Comment: one quick question. How does you determine the probability of each disease?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant way of doing it, but it should work, assuming you're using MySql:

```
select *
from 
(
    select d.d_name, d.d_desc, GROUP_CONCAT(sd.s_id SEPARATOR ',') s_ids
    from Diseases  d , Symptom_disease sd
    where sd.d_id = d.d_id
    group by d.d_name, d.d_desc
    order by sd.s_id
) as t
where t.s_ids = '1,2,3'
;
```

You need to make sure you concatenate all the sympton ids in ascending order in the where clause of the outer select ( where t.s_ids = '1,2,3'), and it should give you only the diseases whose symptons match exactly the ones your users selected.